# Pass a swift closure to an objective-C function which takes a block as parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdictionary, swift-dictionary

I have a function in objective-C as following

```
- (void) fetchChannelListForWatch:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))callback
```

I want to pass a swift callback closure into this like this:

```
fetchChannelListForWatch(replyHandler)
```

where replyHandler is a closure of type

```
replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)
```

and I get the error:

```
Cannot invoke 'fetchChannelListForWatch' with an argument list of type '(([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)'
```

The replyHandler is coming from WatchConnectivity delegate

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)
```

so I cannot change the type of replyHandler.

How can I pass my swift closure with parameter

```
replyHandler: [String: AnyObject] -> ()
```

into an objective-C function that takes a block with parameter

```
- (void) fetchChannelListForWatch:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))callback
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: It would be easier to read for us if you just pasted the code here (and mark it as such) instead of using images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be a shortcut to your problem:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void){
      let objCObject = ObjectiveCClass()

      objCObject.fetchChannelListForWatch { (dict) -> Void in
            replyHandler(dict as! [String : AnyObject]?)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The bridged type for NSDictionary is

```
[NSObject: AnyObject]
```

In your case you need to update your `replyHandler` to

```
replyHandler: ([NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Void)
```

Here is the relevant documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

Comment: Hey @Ben, thanks for the information. But in my case, the replyHandler is part of a delegate callback. specifically the didReceiveMessage function from WatchConnectivity. So I can't change the type of my replyHandler, casting it to ([NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Void) doesn't work either. Would you know how to get around this? Thanks!